# 'Int object not callable'

Tags: python, integer, variance

I am attempting to calculate the variance of my list without using the sum function or other libraries. No matter what I change, I receive 'int object is not callable'. This is what I have so far.

```
sum2 = 0
total_len = len(class_list)
for i in range(total_len):
    the_sum2 = the_sum2 + (class_list[i] - total_mean)**2
var = the_sum2 / len(class_list)
```

Comment: You're missing some variable definitions (`class_list` for example), and the complete output of the error.

Comment: can you please put whole code, some parts are missing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Aside for what @BeRT2me mentioned, shouldn't ```sum2 = 0``` be ```the_sum2 = 0```?

Comment: Please add the full traceback. If the error comes up in `total_len = len(class_list)` you have overwritten `len` somewhere in the code that you didn't show.

Answer (score -1):

@Ella you can try like this it will give you solution

```
import numpy as np
the_sum2 = 0
class_list = [1,2,2,3,4,5]
total_len = len(class_list)
mean = np.mean(class_list)
for i in range(total_len):
    the_sum2 = the_sum2 + (class_list[i] - mean)**2
var = the_sum2 / len(class_list)
print(var)
```

Comment: importing numpy definitely breaks OPs requirements of 'not using other libraries'

Comment: Try to be more concise and maybe use comments to explain your answer :)